# ProGuard Java libraries path

Tags: java, proguard

I have a saved ProGuard thing, in it, I have this line:

```
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

I use this profile thing on both Linux and Windows. I have a portable hard drive that has this file on it and to reference libraries that I got, I can use the `../lib/aLibrary.jar`. Is there a way I can get the location of rt.jar on both platforms so I don't have to change the path to the jar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

ProGuard automatically replaces the Java system property `java.home` for you. This of course assumes that you are running ProGuard with the intended Java 7 JVM on each platform.

You could also specify your own java system property, say `target.java.home`:

```
-libraryjars <target.java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

You then need to define this property on the command-line when you run ProGuard:

```
java -Dtarget.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre -jar lib/proguard.jar .....
```